# Objective-C store longitude and latitude in variable

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this code here that gets the latitude and longitude:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        Long.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        Lat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }
}
```

my question is when I move my phone, these values change, I am looking for away to store them into a variable so they very change. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hrrrm...

Yes, it's possible. Trivial even. Simply move your currentLocation out of your function and into the @interface of your class:

```
@interface MyClass
{
  //other instance variables here
  CLLocation *currentLocation;
}
//properties and function definitions go here
@end
```

Then change your function:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *) newLocation 
    fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
   //Now saves to an instance variable instead of a local var.
   if (currentLocation == nil)
     currentLocation = newLocation; 

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        Long.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        Lat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }
}
```

However, it isn't clear what you're asking. That `didUpdateToLocation` method is a delegate method of the location manager, intended to report **CHANGES** in the user's location. What specific location do you want to store, and under what conditions? You want to save the very first location update you get once you ask the location manager to start updating locations? And then what do you want to do with it?

### EDIT:

Note that when you first ask for location updates from the location manager the first location you get often has really horrible accuracy. (It's not uncommon for it to be off by a kilometer or more.) You need to keep checking the horizontal accuracy of the location and wait for the GPS to settle down and give reasonable readings.